# jQuery: Mouseover DIV effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

Apologies for the newbishness of my question, I'm still getting used to jQuery. I wish to do the most simple of effects. One which I've seen on a ton of different websites. Basically just that when a mouse hovers over an email, text appears above it.

I've attempted to make something using jsFiddle, but it's not behaving how I'd expect it to at all. You can see the effect I'm going for, though: http://jsfiddle.net/5dyrJ/

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').on("mouseover", function (){
        $("#slider").animate({"right":"-30%"}, "slow");
    }).on("mouseout", function (){
        $("#slider").animate({"right":"-99%"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Can someone please explain how to efficiently get this effect?

Comment: Here's how -> http://jsfiddle.net/5dyrJ/2/

Comment: Or without javascript at all -> http://jsfiddle.net/5dyrJ/5/

Comment: @adeneo, +1 for pure css solution

Comment: @adeneo you should include .stop() or demonstrate that too.. it has the repeated problem. The OP is new so he should see this too.

Comment: I ended up using the Pure CSS solution. No point in using JS when you don't need to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

The cause of your current problems are that [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)/[`mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) will trigger on entering/leaving child elements.

**Solution:**

You'd use [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead in this case (or the shorthand [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').on("mouseenter", function (){
        $("#slider").animate({"right":"-30%"}, "slow");
    }).on("mouseleave", function (){
        $("#slider").animate({"right":"-99%"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

[**Your jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dyrJ/1/)

**Why does this work?**

This works because `mouseenter()`/`mouseout()` do not trigger when entering/leaving child elements. [Here is a great example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/213/) showing the differences between `mouseover`/`mouseenter`.

Also note that, as @adeneo as shown in his jsFiddle, your example can actually be done just using CSS by combining [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) state.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is that because the mouse pointer isn't "over" `#main` when `#slider` appears?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> **DESCRIPTION:**  Description: Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the
>   elements.

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').hover(function() {
        $("#slider").animate({"right":"-30%"}, "slow");
    }, function (){
        $("#slider").animate({"right":"-99%"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dyrJ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
$('#main').on("mouseover", function (){
    $("#slider").animate({"right":"-30%"}, "slow");
}).on("mouseleave", function (){
    $("#slider").animate({"right":"-99%"}, "fast");
});
});
```

Hope this helps!